# Error in Join query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 4 tables **`tbl_user`, `tbl_usedetails`,`tbl_aboutme`,`tbl_looking`** contains details of different users. These four tables have a field named **userid** in common. I want to join these four tables with the **userid**.

Consider my user id as 3

**`tbl_user`** is the root table where the `userid` is always present. **But in other tables, `userid` may or may not be present.**

I tried the following query but it fetch the `userdetails` with `userid` not equal to 3

```
select  *  
from `tbl_user` as u,
`tbl_usedetails` as ud,
`tbl_aboutme` as a,
`tbl_looking` as l 
where (u.`userid`=ud.`userid` OR a.`userid`=l.`userid` ) 
AND (u.`userid`='3')
```

**`tbl_usedetails`** didnt have the row with **userid** 3, but it contains another row with **userid** 13, When execute query it also joins the row with the **userid** 13.

Comment: @Arun Prasanth Query joining tables with different userid

Comment: is userid UNIQUE in all tables if not NULL? I think you can do a series of nested LEFT JOINs with u.userid=(next table).userid...

Comment: @RobP userid is unique

Comment: can you please provide sample data in your table and then put a sample output you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not 100% clear and unambiguous but I think you want to pick up values from other tables where present. If rows are not present for a user in three of the tables, you still want results from other tables. That's a `LEFT JOIN`, as follows:

```
SELECT  *  
FROM `tbl_user` AS u 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_usedetails` AS ud ON u.userd = ud.userid
LEFT JOIN `tbl_aboutme` AS a ON u.userd = a.userid
LEFT JOIN `tbl_looking ` AS l ON u.userd = l.userid
WHERE u.`userid` = '3'
```

Answer (score 1):

try outer join so that you get the data even though there is no data in secondary table.

```
select  *  
from `tbl_user` as u,
left outer join tbl_usedetails ud on u.userid=ud.userid
left outer join tbl_aboutme a on a.userid=u.userid
left outer join tbl_looking l on l.userid=u.userid
where  
u.userid='3'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     select  *  from `tbl_user` as u,`tbl_usedetails` 
as ud,`tbl_aboutme` as a,`tbl_looking` as l where 
(u.`userid`=ud.`userid` OR a.`userid`=l.`userid` ) 
AND (u.`userid`='3')
```

add condition to `ud table`